# Google Analytics regex, match URLs that do NOT end with specific strings

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics, regex-lookarounds

In Google Analytics, I am trying to filter URLs that start a specific way, and do NOT end with certain strings. For example, I want URLs that start with this: start_string/, but do NOT end with, say, stringone or stringtwo.

However, GA does not seem to allow negative lookahead.

So, I want something of the form: ^start_string/()$, where I want to have an expression in the parentheses that omits URLs ending with stringone or stringtwo.

Answer (score 0):

How about this method?

1. Retrieve values that begin with "start_string".
2. Not retrieve values that end with "stringone".
3. Not retrieve values that end with "stringtwo".

These patterns are used as "AND" as follows.

[image]

When you use this, please use as "Advanced Filter ON".

If this was not a method what you want, or if I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: That works just fine, but I'm actually curious what the regex expression would look like. I may want to call the GA API in Python and will need a literal regular expression string to filter things in this way.